# small problem in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

i have small problem in my sql query

my tables

```
 /*  threads
    thread_id/thread_title/thread_content
    1 / any post title / welcome to my post
    relations
    cate_id/thread_id
    1 / 1
    2 / 1
    categories
    category_id/category_name
    1 / some_cate
    2 / second_cate
    */
```

My sql query

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT t.*,c.*, GROUP_CONCAT(r.cate_id SEPARATOR ' ') as cate_id 
FROM threads as t
LEFT JOIN relations as r on r.thread_id = t.thread_id
LEFT JOIN categories as c on c.category_id = r.cate_id
GROUP BY r.thread_id
");
```

php code

```
while($thread = mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo 'Post title is: ' . $thread['thread_title'] . '<br />'; // work fine
    echo 'Post content is: ' . $thread['thread_content'] . '<br />'; //work fine
    echo 'Categories id is : ' . $thread['cate_id'] . '/' . '<br />'; //  cate_id of relations table work fine
    echo 'Categories names is : ' . $thread['category_name'] . '/'; // category name of categories table don't work fine
    echo '-------End of first POOOOOOOOOOOST--------';
}
```

OUTPUT

```
/*
any post title
welcome to my post
1/2
some_cate/
-------End of first POOOOOOOOOOOST-------
*/
```

Now my problem is!

There is small problem in query

there is two categories id (1 and 2)

should be there is two categories name!

some_cate / second_cate

but it display only one! though it display two categories id!

categories names does not repeat

but the categories id is repeat! and working fine

@@Doug Kress

i tryid your code but there is problem in your code with mysql_fetch_array

i got duplication of posts!

```
any post title
welcome to my post
some_cate/

any post title
welcome to my post
second_cate/
```

i am using CONCAT and GROUP BY to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually in the GROuP BY - you're telling it to group by r.thread_id - based on your example, there's only one thread_id (1), so it will only return one record.

I'm guessing you don't need the GROUP BY or the GROUP_CONCAt at all.

```
SELECT t.thread_title, t.thread_content, r.cate, c.category_name
FROM threads as t
LEFT JOIN relations as r on r.thread_id = t.thread_id
LEFT JOIN categories as c on c.category_id = r.cate_id
```

It's usually best to specify all of the fields that you're going to use. Otherwise, it's unnecessary work for MySQL and for PHP, and it doesn't make your intent very clear.

I don't know the data, but based on your sample, you could change the LEFT join to an INNER join.

Comment: there is problem in this query for this reason i am using the CONCAT and GROUP BY the problem is : i getting duplication of posts ..example (any post title
welcome to my post
some_cate/

any post title
welcome to my post
second_cate/) that's because i am using mysql_fetch_array

Comment: @@Doug Kress also i am telling it group by r.thread_id <- this is relation table (2 results not 1)

Answer (score 0):

You must add `GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name, ' ') as category_name` at your SELECT statement

If you will meet problem with same column name then just rename category_name to something else.